# Create dictionary of multiple Twitter users' followers with Tweepy - get around 5000 per page limit

Tags: python, tweepy

I am working on a project using Tweepy where I need to first grab all followers for a particular Twitter user, and then do the same for all of those followers' followers. I would like to store the latter part in a dictionary where the keys are the first set of followers, and the values are a list of their followers.

Here is my code:

```
followers_dict = {}
for h in myHandleList:
    try:
        c = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id = h)
        for page in c.pages():
            followers_dict[h] = page
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        pass
```

This code works well for users with under 5000 followers. However, for users with more than 5000 followers, when I run the same code, the code splits their followers into separate lists of no more than 5000 values, and then only adds the second list as values in the dictionary.

For example, one user has 5,400 followers, so when I download their followers, it is formatted as two lists of 5000 and 400. When I use my loop to add their followers to a dictionary, it only adds the second list of 400. I would like to add all 5,400 as values in the dictionary.

I am a noob when it comes to Python, and as someone pointed out in the comments, this is surely an issue with my code - Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "and then only adds the second list as values in the dictionary" - no, that's not tweepy, that's you. It's your job to append entries to existing list instead of replacing it.

Comment: "it only adds the second list of 400" - no. What happens is, 1) list of 5000 followers is added. 2) that list is replaced with another one, containing only 400 followers.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks for pointing that out. As I am pretty new to Python, any suggestions for how to do that?

Comment: I'd start with googling something like "python append list to another list".